# Android Studio - tools.jar error while trying to build the project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to run the mlkit demo application from github on my local setup in Android studio , but when i am trying to build i am getting below error
"Cannot determine path to 'tools.jar' library for Android API 26 Platform (C:/Users//AppData/Local/Android/Sdk)"
I have tried installing jdk 8 which has tools.jar and put the java home path to the same jdk path but still error persists

Also when i try for android app bundle i get another issue as gradle plugin should be 3.2 or higher although my gradle plugin is higher than 3.2

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please post a solution if you discover it. This is stmying me too.